# How do I encrypt a password using command line arguments?

Tags: powershell, encryption, passwords

I need a way to encrypt a password using a command line argument while in the console without prompting via `Get-Credential`. Example:

```
.\Script.ps1 -User Blah -Password ********
```

I have tried several different methods, using the type securestring and trying to pass `Read-Host` into the parameter but everything so far continue to display clear text in the console.

Here is what I have tried.

```
param ( 
   [string]$user,
   [securestring]$password)

param (
   [string]$user,
   [string]$password = $(Read-Host -AsSecureString))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show the code you've tried. It's unclear what you need exactly since we can't see how it's supposed to be used, and why you can't use `Get-Credential`.

Comment: I showed above what I need. When I dot source the script in the console I need to be able to run it like this: .\Script.ps1 -User Blah -Password ********

Comment: This site isn't for you to post what you need and for us to write it for you. You've said you tried some things that didn't work. We could help you figure out why. As it is, you haven't explained 1) Why you can't use `Get-Credential` (arguably the right way to do this), 2) why `Read-Host` didn't work, 3) what the credentials are used for, 4) the way you are invoking the script (you just described it as dot sourcing, but that's not what you show in your question).

Comment: I see your latest edit and that helps but if you could edit in the error it would be helpful.

Comment: There is no error, just when I use the password parameter it is displayed in clear text not encrypted (.\Script.ps1 -User Blah -Password PwdClear). 1)I don't want to use Get-Cred because I want to keep it all on the console line and not have popups. 2) Read-Host in my example above didnt encrypt the password 3) the creds are used to connect to a vCenter 4) I am invoking the script from the console using the text I typed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your password is `thePassword`.

You cannot just do `.\Script.ps1 -user "Blah" -password "thePassword"` and expect the `thePassword` to become `***********`.

Here are some of the things you can do.
First, make sure your parameter types are correct. The reason your second parameter set does work is that you made the type of `$password` a `[String]`. Instead, your parameter list should look like the following.

```
param(
  [String]$user,
  [SecureString]$password = $(Read-Host -AsSecureString)
)
```

Now, with this code, if you do the following, it will fail.

```
.\Script.ps1 -user "Blah" -password "thePassword"
```

This is because `"thePassword"` is `[String]` and not `[SecureString]`.

If you want to actually be able to pass the password into the script, you can create the `[SecureString]` outside calling the script, or have a wrapper script that calls `Script.ps1`, or a few other ways. For example...

```
# Doing it Manually in two lines
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
.\Script.ps1 -user "Blah" -password $password
```

OR

```
# Doing it Manually in one line
.\Script.ps1 -user "Blah" -password $(Read-Host -AsSecureString)
```

OR

```
# Taking advantage of the Default Value for $password
.\Script.ps1 -user "Blah"
# Will automatically prompt for $password upon executing
```

OR

```
# Doing it in a Wrapper Script
# You can save the following in a separate script
# OR you can add it to Script.ps1 itself
$user = Read-Host "Enter Username"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Password"
.\Script.ps1 -user $user -password $password
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will start heading in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, from your comments I think I understand your issue better now.

You want to invoke a script from the command line and provide a masked password parameter, without waiting for it to prompt you.

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this.

Your second parameter block that uses `Read-Host -AsSecureString` will work as long as you don't supply `-password` at all. The script will then prompt you for the password and it will be masked.

But this is basically the same as using `Get-Credential`.

Comment: Ok that I was I was afraid of. I tried several different things and could never get anything to work so I figured I would see if I was maybe missing something. Thank you for your time and looking at it.

Comment: @jrob24 just curious why prompting is not an option for you if you're intending to invoke the script interactively anyway?

Comment: I was a matter of preference honestly and see exactly if another option was available I could use. Since there is not looks like I will have to go that route.

Comment: @jrob24 ok, in that case I really recommend using a single `[PSCredential]` object rather than a separate user name and password. It's easier to manage, kept securely, etc.